How to get the RouteData from Uri using DefaultHttpContext
I'm migrating my code from .net4.8 framework to .net 8 MVC project
Earlier we used this code to fetch the controller name from the Uri
public class GetRouteDataContext : HttpContextBase
{
    public override HttpRequestBase Request { get; }

    private RouteDataContext(Uri uri)
    {
        var url = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
        var qs = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Query, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
        Request = new HttpRequestWrapper(new HttpRequest(null, url, qs));
    }

    public static RouteValueDictionary RouteValuesFromUri(Uri uri)
    {
        return RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new RouteDataContext(uri)).Values;
    }
}

Now we cant use this HttpContextBase, HttpRequestBase, HttpRequestWrapper and RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new RouteDataContext(uri)) to get the RouteData
Need help to get the RouteData with alternative approach. I'm not confident with the code that i have written.
I have tried to fetch the routeValues from the Uri with the help of EndpointDataSource in the HttpContext
public class GetRouteDataContext 
{
    private static HttpContext _httpContext => new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
    public HttpContext HttpContext { get; }

    // Constructor to initialize HttpContext from the given Uri
    public GetRouteDataContext(Uri uri)
    {
        var qs = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Query, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
        qs = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qs) ? (qs.Contains('?') ? qs : "?" + qs) : qs;
        HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            Request = {
                Scheme = uri.Scheme,
                Host = new HostString(uri.Host),
                Path = new PathString(uri.AbsolutePath),
                QueryString = new QueryString(qs)
            },
        };
    }

    public RouteValueDictionary RouteValuesFromUri(Uri uri)
    {
        var routeContext = new GetRouteDataContext(uri);
        // Use HttpContext to get route data
        var routeData = GetRouteData(routeContext.HttpContext);

        return routeData?.Values ?? new RouteValueDictionary();
    }

    // Manually resolve route data using EndpointDataSource
    private RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var endpointDataSource = _httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<EndpointDataSource>();

        var routeContext = new RouteContext(httpContext);

        foreach (var endpoint in endpointDataSource.Endpoints)
        {
            if (endpoint is RouteEndpoint routeEndpoint && routeEndpoint.RoutePattern != null)
            {
                var routeValues = routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.RequiredValues;
                var meta = routeEndpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();
                string endpointUrl = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", meta.ControllerName, meta.ActionName);
                if (httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().Contains(endpointUrl))
                {
                    routeContext.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", routeValues["controller"]);
                    routeContext.RouteData.Values.Add("action", routeValues["action"]);

                    return routeContext.RouteData;
                }
            }
        }

        return null; // No matching route found
    }

}

Kindly suggest alternative approach/efficient way of getting the routeValues.
Note: I'm new to .net core and migrating code

Create a new class:
public class RouteDataExtractor
{
    public static RouteData GetRouteData(Uri uri, IRouteCollection routes)
    {
        // Create a default HttpContext
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddRouting();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            RequestServices = serviceProvider
        };

        // Set the request path from the provided URI
        httpContext.Request.Path = uri.LocalPath;
        httpContext.Request.Host = new HostString(uri.Host);

        // Create a RouteData object to hold the matched route data
        var routeContext = new RouteContext(httpContext);

        // Route matching
        var route = routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        return route;
    }
}

Then use that class in middleware:
public class RouteDataMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RouteDataMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Extract RouteData from the current HttpContext
        var routeData = context.GetRouteData();

        if (routeData != null)
        {
            // Store the route data in HttpContext.Items so it can be accessed later
             context.Items["RouteController"] = routeData.Values["controller"];
             context.Items["RouteAction"] = routeData.Values["action"];
             context.Items["RouteId"] = routeData.Values["id"];
        }

        // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
        await _next(context);
    }
}

Then add this middleware in StartUp class and its configure method:
app.UseMiddleware<RouteDataMiddleware>();

At last, use the context in your controller:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Access the data stored in HttpContext.Items by RouteDataMiddleware
        var controllerName = HttpContext.Items["RouteController"]?.ToString();
        var actionName = HttpContext.Items["RouteAction"]?.ToString();
        var routeId = HttpContext.Items["RouteId"]?.ToString();

        // Example: Use the extracted route data for logging or custom logic
        Console.WriteLine($"Middleware stored Controller: {controllerName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Middleware stored Action: {actionName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Middleware stored RouteId: {routeId}");

        // Render the view or return the response
        return View();
    }
}


What is this routeBuilder? how can i access it in the controller?
Im getting error for  routes.GetRouteData(httpContext) as No overload for method 'GetRouteData' takes 1 arguments

@Ranjini review my updated code.

okay now i have a problem.  In the controller, I have the Referrer Url which i convert to Uri and then try to find the controller name using that GetRouteDataContext.().

sorry but not understanding what you mean, its simple, you just need to store all the information in httpcontext for the route that you need, and then access it in controller. try and debug the RouteDataMiddleware and RouteDataExtractor

I tried still not able to access the routeData using the middleware that you have suggested.
I'm taking the referrer url like this Request.Headers.Referer.ToString() then passing it to the GetRouteDataContext.RouteValuesFromUri(new Uri(Request.Headers.Referer.ToString())).
I also changed the logic in the RouteValuesFromUri to var routeData = GetRouteData(routeContext.HttpContext); to var routeData = routeContext.HttpContext.GetRouteData(); --> count is 0

First of all, HttpContext has method GetRouteValue which is perfect fit.
Additionally, instance of HttpContext is inherited from base controller  ControllerBase.
So it is enough to implement something like below:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(new 
        { 
            Controller = HttpContext.GetRouteValue("controller")?.ToString() 
        });
    }
}

